# как отдать клиенту ios приложение для тестирования

Tags: ios, xcode, тестирование

Я разработал приложение для *ios* 12 в *xcode 10.1* , такой вопрос: как мне отдать человеку приложения для тестирования не имея аккаунт разработчика, возможно ли это? Пробовал пользоваться *testFlight* по инструкции в интернете. Нужно зайти на [сайт](https://itunesconnect.apple.com)  и выбрать раздел приложение, но при переходе пишет **страница не найдена**, прошу сильно не пинать я только начинаю разбираться в *ios* разработке, за любые советы заранее благодарен!

Comment: нужно иметь акк разработчика, вы выгружаете в эпл свое приложение и там уже распространяете его через testflight, иначе возможности мне кажется нет. Это не андроид где можно инсталлер скинуть и все (насколько я знаю)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный вариант - приобрести аккаунт разработчика `клиенту` и пригласить Вас в команду или дать доступ к этому аккаунту, где уже и настроить всё для тестирования (пригласить тестировщиков / внутреннее тестирование / внешнее тестирование)

Менее правильный - сделать то же самое под своим аккаунтом разработчика. Но потом то же самое нужно будет проделывать для клиента, так как для публикации все-равно ему нужно будет приобрести аккаунт.

Более экзотические варианты - установить непосредственно на его устройство удалённо или использовать что-то вроде https://appetize.io . (Не в курсе, остались ли ещё его аналоги). Можно просто записать видео работы приложения :)

Comment: В вопросе речь просто про некого человека-тестера, не факт, что это заказчик

Answer (score 0):

**1 вариант:** подключить устройство тестировщика к вашему Mac и установить через кабель из xCode - если вы физически можете встретиться.

**2 вариант:** получить UDID его устройства (что такое UDID, и как его получить: https://skalolaskovy.ru/ios/257-udid), добавить его в список "аккредитованных" устройств на сайте https://developer.apple.com в разделе "**Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles**".

Создать Ad Hoc Distribution Profile.

Затем сделать сборку приложения (получить ipa-файл) с использованием этого профиля. ipa-файл отправить тестеру, он сможет установить его с помощью iTools, iMazing, Apple Configurator 2 или через сайт **DIAWI.COM**

Приложение будет работать до конца срока жизни профиля (1 год с момента его создания, но не более срока годности сертификата, которым данный профиль был подписан).

**3 вариант:** Использовать Test Flight (это проще и быстрее, чем вариант 2, особенно, если в процессе разработки и тестирования вы часто будете делать новые сборки приложения, но приложение будет "жить" только 90 дней).

Для этого нужно авторизоваться на сайте https://developer.apple.com, перейти в App Store Connect и создать Новое приложение, оформить его страницу по минимуму, потом в разделе Test Flight настроить альфа-тестирование (для зарегистрированных в качестве разработчиков в вашей учетке) или бета-тестирование (для любых сторонных Apple ID).

Описывать это тут подробно - долго и нет смысла (в сети полно шпаргалок об этом, в том числе официальная документация от Apple), если нужна помощь, могу один раз показать, как это сделать.

**4 вариант:** Если есть Enterprise-аккаунт разработчика Apple (за 299$ который), создать Enterprise (InHouse) Distribution Profile (аналогочно варианту 2, но без UDID), создать ipa-файл приложения - его можно будет установить на любое устройство (которое соответствует настройкам, указанным вами в xCode для проекта - тип устройства, версия iOS).

Comment: Если  4 вариант не возможен, но лучше использовать 3 вариант.